# Should I use tableViewController or regular viewController to recreate the reminders detail view?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, tableview, viewcontroller

Hi I'm new to swift and I'm trying to create a similar looking app as the reminders app. I would like to know how I'm I supposed to create the DetailView from the reminders app were some cells have spaces in between and some do not. [The view I'm trying to recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4e2LA.png)

Comment: The spaces between the cells are called `section headers`. There are three sections in the image you provided. So basically you are seeing 3 spaces which are colored as _light gray_

Comment: You can always make a regular `UIViewController` act like a `UITableViewController` by a) giving it a `UITableView`, b) making it conform to `UITableViewDelegate`, and c) making it conform to `UITableViewDataSource`. With a regular `UIViewController`, you have a little more freedom as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My opinion is to use UIViewController. Because you have more control on it.**

**UITableViewController :**

If you use `UITableViewController`, it will some default features. When you create one in the storyboard/Xib,

It will handle following behaviours if use a UITableViewController.

- TableView creation
- clears selection on ViewWillAppear
- RefreshControl.

**UIViewController :**

You can do all the above features if you use **UIViewController**, but you have write a code for that.

Lets assume, if you get a change request to add some custom view next to tableview and top of the `tableview` then its easy to implement in `UIViewController`.

Go with **`UIViewController`** if you need more control on you page.

Comment: How would i add components such as a calendar showing under the remind me on day if the switch is on in a UIViewController instead of UITableViewController? If I use the TableViewController I *think* I could just insert a cell under the remind me on day cell with the calendar showing in it.

Comment: Each one is a different type of cells. based on cell selection show date picker. once the date is selected then reload the particular cell with a selected date.

Comment: Use the tableview style as `UITableViewStyleGrouped`. You will get similar look.  `walk dog` cells are in one section. `Remind me`, `Alarm` and `Repeat` are under one section, `Priority`,`List` and `Notes` cells are under another section. Total your to use 3 sections